# Sketching points given by complex numbers

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

I cannot remember much about circles. If I have $|z-1+i|=1$, how do I translate this geometrically. I know it's a circle but I can't remember how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$|z+i-1|=1.$$

if $z=x+iy$ we then have

$$|x+iy+i-1|=1,$$

$$|(x-1)+i(y+1)|=1.$$

Recalling the definition of $|z|$ we have

$$\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2}=1,$$

$$\implies (x-1)^2+(y+1)^2=1.$$

Thus, $|z+i-1|=1$ is a circle centered at $(1,-1)$ of radius one.

Comment: ok, i got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @cele When presented with such problems the general technique is to let $z=x+iy$ for $x,y \in \mathbf{R}$. From there, you follow the same procedure of applying the definition of $|z|$.